# How to provide fairness to users in multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, threadpoolexecutor

In our application, we have a threadpool with size 50. Multiple threads logs in to application and threads get assigned to them. The number of threads one user consumes basically depends on the volume of data user is trying to load. Now the issue is: -
 When a high volume user logs in, it starts consuming 40 threads which causes other low volume users to wait. We want to have mechanism in which we provide some fairness to users so that one user don't consume all the threads. Can you please suggest some intelligent solution for this?

Comment: Instead of giving heavy users access to 40 threads, you could limit them to say 10 threads.  This limit can be adjusted based on load.

Comment: This is what we are thinking, I was just wandering if there is something already available which can provide something like this as this is a standard problem.

Comment: the standard solution is to utilise the threading model provided by the OS. Often the best approach is to figure out why this is not working for you.

Comment: It is still a bit rough but functioning: a task queue with quality of service, see the unit test [TestTaskQWithQos](https://github.com/fwi/TaskQ/blob/master/taskq/taskq-core/src/test/java/nl/fw/taskq/TestTaskQWithQos.java) for the idea. I wrote the package with the same kind of requirements as you outlined in mind, but I have not polished the implementation yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is any ready solution to this scenario but you can achieve this by something like following (Not tested so please bear with me if this does not completely work).

User requests are something like -

```
class UserRequest implements Runnable {

    private final int userId;

    public UserRequest(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public void run() {
        // process the request
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
}
```

Now the server is like this -

```
class FairServer {

    private final int maxActiveRequests;
    private final int maxWaitingRequests;
    private final int minActiveRequestPerUser;
    private final int maxActiveRequestsPerUser;
    private final AtomicInteger currentTotalActiveRequests;
    private final Map<Integer, AtomicInteger> currentActiveRequestsPerUser;
    private final BlockingQueue<UserRequest> waitingQueue;
    private final ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor;
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;
    private final Lock lock;
    private AtomicInteger currentLimitPerUser;

    public FairServer(int maxActiveRequests, int maxWaitingRequests, int minActiveRequestPerUser, int maxActiveRequestsPerUser) {
        this.maxActiveRequests = maxActiveRequests;
        this.maxWaitingRequests = maxWaitingRequests;
        this.minActiveRequestPerUser = minActiveRequestPerUser;
        this.maxActiveRequestsPerUser = maxActiveRequestsPerUser;
        this.currentLimitPerUser = new AtomicInteger(0);
        this.currentTotalActiveRequests = new AtomicInteger(0);
        this.currentActiveRequestsPerUser = new HashMap<Integer, AtomicInteger>();
        this.waitingQueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<UserRequest>(maxWaitingRequests, new UserRequestComparator());
        this.lock = new ReentrantLock();
        this.threadPoolExecutor = new LocalThreadPoolExecutor(0, maxActiveRequests, 60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
        this.scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        this.scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new FairnessManager(), 1L, 1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void submitUserRequest(UserRequest userRequest) {
        if (waitingQueue.size() >= maxWaitingRequests) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Max limit reached");
        }
        if (currentTotalActiveRequests.get() < maxActiveRequests) {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                int currentLimit = Math.round(maxActiveRequests / (currentActiveRequestsPerUser.size() == 0 ? 1 : currentActiveRequestsPerUser.size()));
                currentLimitPerUser.set(currentLimit < minActiveRequestPerUser ? minActiveRequestPerUser : (currentLimit > maxActiveRequestsPerUser ? maxActiveRequestsPerUser : currentLimit));
                trySubmit(userRequest);
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        } else {
            // add request to waiting queue and let FairnessManager handle it
            waitingQueue.add(userRequest);
        }

    }

    private void trySubmit(UserRequest userRequest) {
        // directly submit to thread pool executor if less load overall and per user
        AtomicInteger counter = currentActiveRequestsPerUser.get(userRequest.getUserId());
        if (currentTotalActiveRequests.get() < maxActiveRequests && (counter == null || counter.get() < currentLimitPerUser.get())) {
            currentTotalActiveRequests.incrementAndGet();
            if (counter == null) {
                currentActiveRequestsPerUser.put(userRequest.getUserId(), (counter = new AtomicInteger(0)));
            }
            counter.incrementAndGet();
            threadPoolExecutor.submit(userRequest);
        } else {
            // add request to waiting queue and let FairnessManager handle it
            waitingQueue.add(userRequest);
        }
    }

    private class UserRequestComparator implements Comparator<UserRequest> {
        @Override
        public int compare(UserRequest o1, UserRequest o2) {
            AtomicInteger count1 = currentActiveRequestsPerUser.get(o1.getUserId());
            AtomicInteger count2 = currentActiveRequestsPerUser.get(o2.getUserId());
            if (count1 == null) { // this means no current requests by this user
                return -1;
            } else if (count2 == null) { // this means no current requests by this user
                return 1;
            } else {
                return count1.get() <= count2.get() ? -1 : 1; // user with less current requests goes up in the queue
            }
        }
    }

    private class FairnessManager implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            if (!waitingQueue.isEmpty() && currentTotalActiveRequests.get() < maxActiveRequests) {
                lock.lock();
                try {
                    int maxIterations = 5; // just to avoid endless attempts
                    UserRequest userRequest;
                    while (maxIterations-- > 0 && (userRequest = waitingQueue.poll()) != null) {
                        trySubmit(userRequest);
                    }
                } finally {
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class LocalThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
        public LocalThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
            super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
        }

        @Override
        protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
            super.afterExecute(r, t);
            if (r instanceof UserRequest) {
                currentTotalActiveRequests.decrementAndGet();
                int userId = ((UserRequest) r).getUserId();
                lock.lock();
                try {
                    int count = currentActiveRequestsPerUser.get(userId).decrementAndGet();
                    if (count == 0) {
                        currentActiveRequestsPerUser.remove(userId);
                    }
                } finally {
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The user request is submitted to server through `submitUserRequest(UserRequest userRequest)` and it either directly submits it to thread pool manager or keeps the request waiting if there are more number of requests from same user or overall in the server. You need to define min and max number of requests per user and then server dynamically adjusts the limit per user depending upon the current load.
The server has an internal thread which clears the waiting queue.

Answer (score 2):

Use semaphores to control which thread has to wait / sleep and which can go on.
The more users log in, the more heavy user threads are put to sleep.

When threads complete, you can awake the sleeping ones.

If you can change server settings, allow 50 threads for every user, then sleep them when needed. That way you can allow one user full speed and slow him down on a fair basis. Sleep means thread will pause and stop using CPU time until awakened.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a rate limiter. Guava has it. 
http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html

For instance, you can limit the number of actions per second that is triggered by a user and leave room for others.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to use a [BlockingPriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html) as the work queue for the ThreadPoolExecutor.  Then wrap each task  with an object that knows the number of requests a user is trying to load such that when that number is less than other it should move up in priority

```
public class PriorityTask implements Comparable<Task>, Runnable {
    private final Runnable task;
    private final int request;

    public PriorityTask(Runnable task, int request) { .. }

    public void run(){
       task.run();
    }

    public int compareTo(Task task){
       return this.request > task.request ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

So high load users will back off for low load users. This obviously can result in starvation for high load users.  To avoid starvation you can also add in a `Date` field which says, if this task hasn't executed in 10 seconds (as a random time I picked), execute it despite being a high load user.

This isn't necessarily perfect but can help lead you into a direction which makes it work better.